# TypeError: 'Cell' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, django, xlrd

I wanna parse excel and put data in the model(User).
I got an error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/xxx/testapp/app/views.py", line 17, in <module>
    is_man = row[4] != ""
TypeError: 'Cell' object does not support indexing
```

views.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

  book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/data.xlsx')
  sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

  for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        rows = sheet.row(row_index)  
        print(row[1]) 
  for row in rows:
        is_man = row[4] != ""
        user = User(user_id=row[1], name_id=row[2], age=row[3], man=is_man)
        user.save()
```

I think rows is not cell but list,so I really cannot understand why it is called 'Cell' and how should I fix this.
I tried to fix this,so change rows cell into list like

```
for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        rows = sheet.row(row_index) 
        rows = list(rows) 
        print(rows)
```

however,same error happens.What should I do to fix this?
Now,views.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

  book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/data.xlsx')
  sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

  for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
        rows = sheet.row(row_index)  
        print(rows[1]) 
  for row in rows:
        is_man = rows[4] != ""
        user = User(user_id=row[1], name_id=row[2], age=row[3], man=is_man)
        user.save()
```

I saw data in `print(rows[1])` ,so it is

```
user_id
1
2
3
```

so I can only get user_id data.It is not my ideal data,I wanna get each user data like

```
1   1   40      leader
```

I tried to fix this and rewrite `print(rows[1][0])` ,so `TypeError: 'Cell' object does not support indexing` error happens.How should I do my ideal thing?

When I outputed `print(rows[4])`,it is like

```
text:'man'
empty:''
text:'●'
empty:''
```

It is natural because excel data is
[image: excel]

Comment: shouldn't you append `sheet.row(row_index)` to `rows` ?

Comment: @Bijoy I cannot catch ur meaning.So,how should I fix this?

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar the error deleted!!thx!!Now,in this part ,user = User(user_id=row[1], name_id=row[2], age=row[3], man=is_man)  same error happens,so should I change row into rows?(Shouldn't I use row?)

Comment: @user8504021 Though the error is gone, I don't think that's what you wanted. you need to print and check the data.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar yes,u r right.I updated my question,so if u know something,please help me.

Comment: @user8504021 print `rows[4]` and include the output in your question.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar I added my info

Comment: @user8504021 have you tried with sheet.row_values(row_index, start_col_index,end_col_index[optional])

Comment: @user8504021 becoz sheet.row() this returns the `Cell` objects not `Cell` value

Comment: @KaranChudasama thx!! I tried ur codes,so I could get ideal rows data.Should I  change row into rows in this part  user = User(user_id=row[1], name_id=row[2], age=row[3], man=is_man) ?

Comment: @user8504021 depending upon individual values assign it with proper indexing

Comment: use `sheet.row_values()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sheet.row_values(row_index, start_col_index, end_col_index[option])` instead of `sheet.row()` because sheet.row() returns `Cell` objects not the `Cell` values.

I hope this will help you.